# Cannot anchor link to dynamically generated list items, created via Firebase query

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of recommendation headings on page A.  I want each heading to directly link to more details on page B, so that user doesn't have to scroll down to find it.

Both the list of recommendation links on page A, and the recommendations details on page B, are generated via similar Firebase queries, according to logged in user's account data.

Here is the page A query, to create the list of links:

```
    // list a hyperlink for each recommendation made for this report
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = '<a href="recommendations.html#recommend' + child.val().number + '"><b>' + child.val().number + '</b> - ' + child.val().title + '</a>';
            recommendationsCalloutList.appendChild(p);

});
```

For page A, the outputted html for each link looks like this:

```
<a href="recommendations.html#recommend1"><b>1 - Eat some sushi</a>
```

Here is the page B query:

```
// list each active recommendation for this account
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var h3 = document.createElement('h3');

        h3.innerHTML = '<b id="recommend' + child.val().number + '">' + child.val().number + '</b> - ' + child.val().title;

    // populate div with the dynamically generated HTML elements
        activeRecommendationsList.appendChild(div);
        div.appendChild(h3);

});
```

If you notice id of the H3 element is appending same 'child.val().number' variable as the anchor links generated for page A.

Here is the page B HTML:

```
<section id="activeRecommendationsList">
<div><h3><b id="recommend1">1</b> - Eat some sushi</h3></div>
</section>
```

I have the links to the scripts below the DOM elements if that helps.

This is my first post, so sorry if not clear.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Am still having this issue, thanks!